# Adding UITapGestureRecognizer to UINavigationBar overrides ability to use ScrollToTop

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, uigesturerecognizer

So Ive added a TapGestureRecognizer to the navigation bar in order to "pull down" another view, thus its a UIPanGesture Recognizer. The problem is when this gesture is added the UITableView scrollToTop method no longer works, even if enabled before or after the addition of the gesture recognizer.

Has anyone ever experienced or can think of an easy solution?

Thanks!

Heres My Code:

```
if (!pan) {
    _pan = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(panaction:)];
   [_pan setMaximumNumberOfTouches:1];
}

_pan.delegate = self;
[self.navigationController.navigationBar addGestureRecognizer:_pan];
```

EDIT:

Ok, the problem seems to be adding a UIView as a subview in order to drag down from the UINavigation bar, when I dont add the subview the scrollToTop works fine, once its added it must be intercepting the touch event underneath the status bar..

Comment: The scrollToTop does not work with the navigationBar, but the status bar. Did I miss something?

Comment: I tried you setup - works for me, try to describe it in a bit more details, also override `scrollViewShouldScrollToTop:` to see if it gets called at all, in general, David is right – scroll to the top is gesture performed on status bar not the navigation bar

Comment: Thanks guys, I agree, I know its on the status bar which doesnt make any sense, Ill try to override that method and let you know what happens

Comment: @Alexander Zats, how did you set it up.. it looks like scrollViewShouldScrollToTop is not getting called when the gesture recognizer is added to the nav bar, I added what Im doing above, seems pretty straightforward..